# Authorize method usage using PostSharp AOP

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp

I am using a custom claim based authorization in order to create a panel with functions depending on the users access rights. The user claims are stored in a cache `ICashClient`.
The particular menus simply refer to certain controller methods.

Problem is:
It is possible to make use of methods that are not supposed to be available due to missing access rights by simply entering the direct link to the particular method.

My idea is to create an aspect so that these particular methods can be tagged in order to prevent them from beeing executed unallowed.

I want to authorize in the `OnEntry` method again.

Following example allows to check wether an request to the servcer is of type `Ajax` or not.

```
 public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {

            var controller = args.Instance as MyController;

            if (controller != null)
            {

                if (!controller.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                    throw new Exception ($"{args.Method.Name} invalid AJAX request");
            }

            base.OnEntry(args);
        }
```

What possiblities do I have in the context of this `OnEntry` method to query existing data from the cash?
How can I make this cash accessable from there?

**Edit:**
My controllers use (using dependency injection) a so called `QueryProcessor` for retrieving requested data which has following method:

```
 public TResult ExecuteWithCache<TResult>(ICustomQuery<TResult> query)
        {
            try
            {
                //class for creating fingerprint of query 
                var customQueryHash = (ICustomQueryHash<TResult>)query;

                //fingerprint of the query 
                var queryString = customQueryHash.GetQueryHash();    

                //cash which might holds data
                var cachedResult = _cacheClient.Get<TResult>(queryString);




                 ...
             }
             catch(){}


  }
```

The `_cashClient` is an implementation of an extended ICashClient.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you access the cache from your code at the moment?

Comment: updated description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you need to access a dependency in your custom aspect class and this dependency is normally resolved using dependency injection. In this particular case you want to access an instance of the `QueryProcessor`.

Dependencies of the aspects cannot be automatically resolved by a dependency injection framework because the framework doesn't have control of aspects construction and lifetime. There are however a number of approaches available to consume dependencies inside aspects. They are described in this documentation section: http://doc.postsharp.net/consuming-dependencies

Below is the short description for some of the ways to consume dependencies from aspects. You can choose the best approach based on your project and the dependency framework you're using.

[*Global service locator.*](http://doc.postsharp.net/global-service-locator) DI frameworks usually provide a way to query the current object graph for a particular instance (e.g. `context.GetInstance<T>()`).

```
public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
{
    var queryProcessor = ServiceLocator.GetInstance<IQueryProcessor>();
}
```

[*Global composition container*](http://doc.postsharp.net/global-service-container). Some DI frameworks also allow you to satisfy new object's dependencies *after* the initial graph has been constructed. You can override [`RuntimeInitialize`](http://doc.postsharp.net/aspect-initialization) method in your aspect to import the dependencies when the aspect instance is being initialized.

```
[PSerializable]
public class MyAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    [Import]
    public IQueryProcessor QueryProcessor { get; set; }

    public override void RuntimeInitialize(MethodBase method)
    {
        ServiceInjector.BuildObject(this);
    }
}
```

[*Import dependencies from the target object*](http://doc.postsharp.net/importing-dependencies). When the dependencies are stored in properties or fields of the target object, you can import them using [`[ImportMember]`](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_aspects_advices_importmemberattribute) advice. Your aspect has to implement [`IInstanceScopedAspect`](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_aspects_iinstancescopedaspect) in this case.

```
[PSerializable]
public class MyAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect, IInstanceScopedAspect
{
    [ImportMember("QueryProcessor", IsRequired = true)] 
    public Property<IQueryProcessor> QueryProcessor;

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        this.QueryProcessor.Get().ExecuteWithCache(/* ... */);
    }

    object IInstanceScopedAspect.CreateInstance(AdviceArgs adviceArgs)
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    void IInstanceScopedAspect.RuntimeInitializeInstance()
    {
    }
}
```